# My Postfix submission service cannot be accessed remotely

Tags: iptables, postfix

I have a Postfix server that is working on port 25 (SMTP).

I can use Thunderbird to send mails through this Postfix server.

I followed these documentations:

- http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#auxprop_sasldb
- https://wiki.debian.org/PostfixAndSASL#Using_auxprop_with_sasldb

It's easy to configure:

```
$ sudo apt install libsasl2-modules sasl2-bin
$ sudo saslpasswd2 -c -u example.com yugiohjcj
$ sudo sasldblistusers2

$ sudo vim /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5

$ sudo vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
# SASL
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/postfix/sasl
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

$ sudo bash /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Here is how I configure Thunderbird:

- Edit > Account Setttings > Outgoing Server (SMTP)
- Server Name: example.com
- Port: 25
- Connection Security: STARTTLS
- Authentication Method: Normal password
- User Name: yugiohjcj@example.com

However, I know that most of the time ISP are blocking port 25, so it's better to use another port to send my mails.

Thus, I would like to enable port 587 (submission) on my Postfix server.

Here is what I did:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/postfix/master.cf
 submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
   -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
   -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
   -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
   -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
$ sudo bash /etc/init.d/postfix restart
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
```

When I test my server locally, it works:

```
$ telnet localhost 587
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 server.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
[...]
```

But when I test my server remotely, it doesn't work:

```
$ telnet example.com 587
Trying 1.2.3.4...
[...]
```

It is stuck.

Why my Postfix submission service cannot be accessed remotely please?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a problem with the `iptables` command.

I typed these commands:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
```

It's not good because I drop the packets on all ports then I accept the packets on port 587.

So, the packets on port 587 will still be dropped.

I changed the order of the commands:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

And now, my Postfix submission service can be accessed remotely using the `telnet` command.

And I can send a mail through the port 587 with Thunderbird using STARTTLS.

Problem fixed.